# How to display only Maths value in this code

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Here i want display only **Maths** marks,i don't know how to do, i am trying but i am not able to display:-

```html
<?php
$marks1=array(
 array("Maths"=>80,"Physics"=>89,"Chemistry"=>79),
 array("Maths"=>90,"Physics"=>78,"Chemistry"=>87),
 array("Maths"=>78,"Physics"=>90,"Chemistry"=>79)
);
echo "<ul>";
for($r=0;$r<count($marks1);$r++)
{
 echo "<li>";
 foreach($marks1[$r] as $key=>$value)
 {
  echo $key." = ".$value."  ";
 }
 echo "</li>";
 echo "<br><br>";
}
echo "</ul>";

?>
```

Comment: `$marks1[$r]['Maths']`. Make an effort, read php manual.

Comment: `if(key == 'Maths'){echo $key." = ".$value."  ";}`

Comment: oh nice anant now got it,if(key == 'Maths') you missed $

Comment: you should use a `foreach` for both of your loops

Comment: @kanniyappanr  please check the answers below and mark one as accepted which is correct for you.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please prefer using `foreach()` only. And avoid things like `echo "<ul>"` etc.... Follow the below coding format...

```
<?php
  $marks1 = array(
    array("Maths" => 80, "Physics" => 89, "Chemistry" => 79),
    array("Maths" => 90, "Physics" => 78, "Chemistry" => 87),
    array("Maths" => 78, "Physics" => 90, "Chemistry" => 79)
  );
?>

<ul>
  <?php foreach($marks1 as $marks) { ?>
    <li>
      Maths = <?php echo $marks['Maths']; ?>
    </li>
  <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope it's the shortest way to do so-

```
<?php
$marks1=array(
    array("Maths"=>80,"Physics"=>89,"Chemistry"=>79),
    array("Maths"=>90,"Physics"=>78,"Chemistry"=>87),
    array("Maths"=>78,"Physics"=>90,"Chemistry"=>79)
);

foreach($marks1 as $mark){

    echo "MATH = ".$mark['Maths']."<br>";
}

?>
```

**Output :**

```
MATH = 80
MATH = 90
MATH = 78
```